# Clicking a load-button element until it active

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm writing a scrapy spider for Apple Podcasts. And I faced a problem. Let's say I'm scraping a podcast details for this page (https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-art-angle/id1484445852), and i need selenium to click "Show 10 More Episodes" untill this button available, and only after this scrape all loaded data.

```
    def parse_details(self, response):
        #[@class="l-row"]
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get(response) #or url
        
        while True:
            try:
                load_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="link"]')
                load_btn.click()
            except:
                break


        loader = ItemLoader(item=AppleItem(), selector=response)
        name_xpath='//span[@class="product-header__title"]/text()'
        description_css='section.product-hero-desc__section div p::text'
        genre_xpath='//ul[@class="inline-list"]/li/text()'
        rating_css='span.we-customer-ratings__averages__display::text'
        num_of_reviews_css='div.we-customer-ratings__count.small-hide.medium-show::text'
        episodes_css='ul.inline-list.inline-list--truncate-single-line.tracks__track__eyebrow > li > time'
            
        loader.add_xpath('name',name_xpath)
        loader.add_css('description',description_css)
        loader.add_xpath('genre', genre_xpath)
        loader.add_css('rating', rating_css)
        loader.add_css('num_of_reviews', num_of_reviews_css)
        loader.add_css('last_episode', episodes_css)
        loader.add_css('first_episode', episodes_css)


        item = loader.load_item()

        yield item
```

It's seems, I'm doing something very wrong. And It's obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I very recommend for such type of tasks use https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

For example you can wait untill button is available. In example browser waits 15 seconds and check every second availability of the loading button. And for example wait until invisibility of loading div to continue your scraping.

```
from time import sleep    

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expect
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def parse_details(self, response):
    #[@class="l-row"]
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.get(response) #or url
    
    while True:
        try:
            load_btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15, 1).until(
                                    expect.element_to_be_clickable(
                                    (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="link"]')))
            load_btn.click()
            #sleeping until element will became invisible
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15, 1).until(
                          expect.invisibility_of_element_located
                         (By.XPATH, '//[@class="we-loading-spinner we-loading-spinner--small"]')))
            #Going on the bottom of the page if needed
            self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 3999)')
            #Going on the approximate button location
            self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, -900)')
        except:
            break
```